# Can a docker container use the local VPN?

Tags: c#, .net, docker-compose

I have an .Net 6 application that needs to connect to sql server that is only accessible when I'm
connected to the VPN.
The code works fine if I'm only running the .Net application, but when I use the containerized version I'm enable to reach the database.
Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'
services:
          
  cronjob:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}cronjob
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../CronJob/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

and my connection string is the following
`var connectionStringSQL = $"Data Source={sql_data_source}; Initial Catalog = {sql_initial_catalog}; User Id = {sql_user_id}; password = {sql_password}; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = True`

Only the named instance version (databaseXX\YY) works when I run the c# code.
And for the docker compose I have the following error when using the named version
Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName

and when I use the IPAddress:Port I have the following error
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlExceptionSystem.AggregateExceptionSystem.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException", "message": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
connections.

I tried some options in the docker-compose to force it to go through the local vpn
`extra_hosts:  - host.docker.internal:host-gateway`
or     `network_mode: "host"`
but none of them worked, I have exactely the same error